# Generating SelectList with default selected item in MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to generate a selectList with a default selected item in MVC. I assign a selectlist to the viewbag and try to render it in my view and keep getting the below error.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Create the list in my controller:

```
ViewBag.MasterAccountSelect = new SelectList(masterAccountsList, "MasterAccount", "MasterAccount", userSettingsViewModel.MasterAccountName);
```

Render the SelectList in my view:

```
           <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MasterAccountSelect, "MasterAccountSelect")
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownList("MasterAccountSelect")
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MasterAccountSelect)
            </div>
```

I get this error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'UserSettingsViewModel' does not
>   contain a definition for 'MasterAccountSelect' and no extension method
>   'MasterAccountSelect' accepting a first argument of type
>   'UserSettingsViewModel' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

[image: ASP error screenshot]

I also get this error when I

Comment: Your need to show your `UserSettingsViewModel` model (clearly it does not contain a property named `MasterAccountSelect`) But if your using a view model then you should not be using `ViewBag` anyway

Comment: Thanks for the info @StephenMuecke. Can I include a SelectList as part of my viewmodel?

Comment: Yes, and you should. And it appears you want to bind to a property `MasterAccountName`? Is that correct.

Comment: Correct, I tried adding a   list item to the model but I'm getting the below error:

`An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code`

`Additional information: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'MasterAccountSelect'.`

Comment: See my answer below. And remember you need to reassign the SelectList if you return the view in the POST method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You view model does not have a property named `MasterAccountSelect` hence the error. From the code you are assigning to `ViewBag`, you appear to be wanting to bind to a property in your model named `MasterAccountName` in which case your model should be

```
public class UserSettingsViewModel
{
  [Display(Name = "Master Account Name")]
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a master account name")]
  public string MasterAccountName { get; set; }
  public SelectList MasterAccountNameList { get; set; }
  ....
}
```

Then in the GET method

```
UserSettingsViewModel model = new UserSettingsViewModel
{
  MasterAccountName = ..... ,
  MasterAccountNameList = new SelectList(masterAccountsList, "MasterAccount", "MasterAccount")
}
return View(model);
```

And in the view

```
<div class="editor-label">
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MasterAccountName)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MasterAccountName, Model.MasterAccountNameList, "-Please select-")
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.MasterAccountName)
</div>
```

Side note: Since you wanting the options `value` and display text to be the same (using property `MasterAccount`), you can also use

```
MasterAccountNameList = new SelectList(masterAccountsList.Select(x => x.MasterAccount))
```

Answer (score 0):

try `Label` instead of `LabelFor`, You can not use `LabelFor` strictly type html helper if you don't have property in your model.

```
<div class="editor-label">
  @Html.Label("MasterAccountSelect")
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
  @Html.DropDownList("MasterAccountSelect")
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MasterAccountSelect)
</div>
```

**One good Suggestion**
Whenever you are using `Viewbag` for filling dropdown, Keep your Viewbag and property name different because it will not auto select your selected value.